# Enviar valores agrupados en un solo array de un Nodelist a php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, nodejs

Tengo un `div` dentro de un formulario que se duplica `x` cantidad de veces.
Cuando deseo obtener los valores del `div` en un solo `array` para enviarlos a php para luego conectarlos a la base de datos no logro poder enviar el `array` del js.

No se como evaluar ese nodelist

> Notice: Undefined index: texto1 in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\practicas\modelo.php on line 5

JS

```
var form1 = document.getElementById("formprueba");
 form1.addEventListener('submit',function(e){


var txt1 = document.getElementsByName('texto1').value;//no se como evaluarla para poder sacar el array completo.
var txt2 =document.getElementsByName('texto2')[1].value;// al evaluo uno por uno logro sacar el valor individual
var txt3 =document.getElementsByName('texto3')[1].value;

if (1==1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Datos guardados con exito");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'modelo.php',
        data: { "operacion":"registrar","texto1":txt1, "texto2":txt2,"texto3":txt3},
        beforesend: () => { $("#resultado2").html("Espere un momento...") },
        success: (respuesta) => { $("#resultado2").html(respuesta) }
    })
} else {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"); 
}
})
```

HTML

```
<input name="texto1" type="text" " class="form-control" required="">
<input name="texto1" type="text" " class="form-control" required="">
<input name="texto1" type="text" " class="form-control" required="">
```

PHP

```````
 <?php
 include("conexion.php");
 $operacion = "registrar";
 $texto1  =serialize($_POST["texto1"]);//este deberia ser el array del node list
 $texto2 =serialize($_POST["texto2"]);
 $texto3 =serialize($_POST["texto3"]);

  class OPERACIONARRAY extends BD{
public function guardar($texto1,$texto2,$texto3){
    $consulta2 = "INSERT INTO test1(texto1,texto2,texto3) VALUES(?,?,?)";

    try {

        if (1==1) {
            $resultado2 = $this->conexion()->prepare($consulta2);
            $resultado2->execute([$texto1,$texto2,$texto3]);
            echo "Datos registrados";
            echo $texto1;
        } else {
            echo "ERROR" ; 
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo( "Error con la base de datos".$e->getMessage());
        die();
    }

   }
 }

    $operacionarray = new OPERACIONARRAY;

         if ($operacion == "registrar") {
     $operacionarray->guardar($texto1,$texto2,$texto3);
       }``````
```````

Existe alguna forma de sacar los valores de cada `input` del nodelist en javascript y guardarlo todo en un solo `array`.
Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Faltaría el HTML para tener una idea mas clara de que es lo que quieres.

Comment: `<input name="texto1" type="text" " class="form-control" required=""><input name="texto1" type="text" " class="form-control" required=""><input name="texto1" type="text" " class="form-control" required="">`  Esta es la idea tres inputs  con el mismo name, los quiero guardar,quiero los datos obtenidos de ellos en un array para luego usarlo en php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas todos los inputs en un array, puedes usar destructuring `[...document.getElementsByTagName("input")]`, si quieres todos los values, `.map` sobre el destructuring, ejemplos:

```js
const inputs = [...document.getElementsByTagName("input")];

//console.log(inputs); todos los inputs en un array

const values = inputs.map(e => e.value);

console.log(values);
```

```html
<input name="texto1" type="text" value="a" class="form-control" required="">
<input name="texto1" type="text" value="b" class="form-control" required="">
<input name="texto1" type="text" value="c" class="form-control" required="">
```

Comment: Puedo usar un destructuring con [...document.getElementsByName("input")];  , puedo usar BYName  y no BYTagName?

Comment: @DiegoMolina puedes usarlo con lo que quieras, mejor que todo lo anterior es añadir una clase y hacer `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba, el destructuring con el .map me ayudo mucho. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el objeto `FormData` Para enviar todo el contenido de tu formulario (los input)

Ejemplo:

en html si requieres enviar un arreglo de valores de input deberás declararlos así `name="texto[]"`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="texto[]" id="texto1" value="texto1">
<input type="checkbox" name="texto[]" id="texto2" value="texto2">
<input type="checkbox" name="texto[]" id="texto3" value="texto3">
```

en ajax

```
$(document).on('submit','#formprueba', function(){     

        var data = new FormData(this);//this es el formulario del evento    

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'modelo.php',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false, 
            beforesend: () => { $("#resultado2").html("Espere un momento...") },
            success: function(res) {
               alert("Datos guardados")
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("fail");
            }
        })

    })
```

en php accedes como un arreglo ya sea por medio de un ciclo o directamente

```
foreach($_POST["texto"] as $val)
```

ó

```
$_POST["texto"][0];
$_POST["texto"][1];
$_POST["texto"][2];
```

Comment: name="texto[]"  ...  los [] dentro de las comillas afectan?? , no puedo enviar arreglo de valores si uso  name="texto"??

Comment: name="texto[]" es para declararlo como arreglo, osea todos los inputs que tienen ese name="texto[]" pertenecen al arreglo texto el cual va a ser enviado

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza.:

```
var formData = new FormData("miFormulario")
```

Donde miFormulario es tu `id` de formulario. Allí obtendrás toda la `data` de tu formulario, incluyendo los `input` en formato `(key: valor)` y luego hacer con ellos lo que necesites.

Comment: Que pasa si mi formulario es mucho mas amplio y solo quiero agrupar esos tres inputs en un mismo array?